# Object of class couldnt be converted in int

Tags: php, database, session

I have a problem with my code.

I don't understand this error:

> Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in C:\wamp\www\Site\include\fonction_panier.php on line 136

My line 136:

> return $total + $total*$_SESSION['panier']['tva']/100;

This line is in this function:

```
function montantlGlobalTVA() {
    $total = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i<count($_SESSION['panier']['libelleProduit']); $i++) {
        $total += $_SESSION['panier']['qteProduit'][$i]*$_SESSION['panier']['prixProduit'][$i];
    }

    return $total + $total*$_SESSION['panier']['tva']/100;
}
```

TVA is in my database:

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT tva FROM produits");
        $tva = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $_SESSION['panier']['tva']= $tva;
```

When I do a `var_dump()`:

```
<td><?php echo var_dump($_SESSION['panier']['tva'])." %";?></td>
```

I get this result:

> object(stdClass)[1]
>     public 'tva' => string '18' (length=2)

Comment: It is saying that `$_SESSION['panier']['tva']` is not an integer, that means that you cannot do math with it. Echo it and see what it is.

Comment: You can cast using ``(int)`` e.g. ``$total += (int) $_SESSION['panier']['qteProduit'][$i] * (int) $_SESSION['panier']['prixProduit'][$i];``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I bet you're trying to get the value of the column `tva`. When fetching with the strategy `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, each row is returned as an object.

You can get the value by calling the `tva` property set in the object being returned by `fetch()`:

```
$row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$_SESSION['panier']['tva']= $row->tva;
```

Instead of returning the row (object) in the session, the actual value retrieved from the database is now being stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT tva FROM produits");
        $tva = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $_SESSION['panier']['tva']= $tva;
```

Straight form php.net:

PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Maybe you want to use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ?

Comment: When I put PDO::FETCH_ASSOC! I have an other error 

`Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\Site\include\fonction_panier.php on line 136`

I try to remove the division but nothing happen.Do you have an idea?

Comment: This :

`return $total + $total*$_SESSION['panier']['tva']/100;`